# Preventing token injection when replacing substrings

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of key/value strings and a template to replace them in. However, I don't want to replace them twice if one of the values is another token. For example:

```
tokens: [
    Token(Key: "{A}", Value: "{B}"),
    Token(Key: "{B}", Value: "b" )
]

template = "Hello, {A}"

>>> replace(template, tokens)
Actual: "b"
Expected: "{B}"
```

Here's the code:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main {

  public static String replace(String template, Token... tokens) {
    for ( final Token token : tokens ) {
        template = Pattern.compile( token.getKey(), Pattern.LITERAL + Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE )
               .matcher( template )
               .replaceAll( Matcher.quoteReplacement( token.getValue() ) );
    }
    return template;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = replace( "Hello, {A}",
                            new Token("{A}", "{B}"),
                            new Token("{B}", "b" ) );
    System.out.println(result);
  }


  private static class Token {
    String key;
    String value;

    public Token(String key, String value) {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
      return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

This must also work for special characters:

```
replace("{A}", new Token("{A}", "$0.00")) -> "$0.00"
```

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible demo? For example, at  repl.it, ideone.com, tio.run, rextester.com...

Comment: The above code is pretty understandable. It iterates through every token and replaces all instances of its key with its value. However, if a token's value is the next (or a next) token's key, it will be replaced again.

Comment: I know how to fix it, I just would like to test on your data.

Comment: Simply don't iterate over the tokens. Use a pattern that matches any token according to your syntax, `{.*?}` or so, iterate over the matches, and replace with the according token according to some lookup.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://repl.it/repls/CanineStrictMapping#Main.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is to parse the string with the regex only *once*, make only one pass and when you match your key pattern, it is just `{[^{}]*}`, any substring between `{` and `}` with no curly braces in between, check if there is a token with this key in your `Token` list, and if there is, replace with this token value, else, put the matched text back.

You may use

```
public static final Pattern keypattern = Pattern.compile("\\{[^{}]*}");
  
public static Token getTokenByKey(String key, Token... tokens) {
  for ( final Token token : tokens ) {
    if (token.getKey().toUpperCase().equals(key.toUpperCase()))
      return token;
  }
  return null;
}

public static String replace(String template, Token... tokens) {
  Matcher m = keypattern.matcher( template );
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  while (m.find()) {
    Token t = getTokenByKey(m.group(), tokens);
    if (t != null) {
      m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(t.getValue()));
    } else {
      m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group()));
    }
  }
  m.appendTail(sb);
  return sb.toString();
}
```

The main method code executed like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = replace( "Hello, {A} {c}",
                            new Token("{A}", "{B}"),
                            new Token("{B}", "b" ) );
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

will output `Hello, {B} {c}`.

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/eWUMiX).

The `if (token.getKey().toUpperCase().equals(key.toUpperCase()))` line ensures the case insensitive matching.

Comment: This almost works perfectly. However, it breaks if the token value has special characters (`$0.00 -> {A}.00`)

Comment: @MichaelBianconi This is not clear now. What is the token key, what is value? Please edit the question.

Comment: Key: "{A}", Value: "$0.00", Pattern: "{A}", Result: "{A}.00"

Comment: @MichaelBianconi Ok, use `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` to escape the literal replacement pattern correctly.